# How can I create a loop to randomly assign values to each characteristic of an array of class instances

Tags: arrays, loops, class, random, instance

So I am creating a card game that requires different cards, so I created a card class in which I declared the string value names and other integer values that are the powers eg. Intelligence

```
public static class hero{
static String name;
static int strength;
static int intellect;
static int flight;
static int tech;
}
```

So I created an array of instances of these classes.
Their names are read from a text file and assigned to the name value.
Q1) I am having trouble with reading through the file and assigning the string to the name value of each instance of the class.
This is what I've done so far

```
public static void readLines(File f)throws IOException{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
        }
        static File f = new File("C:/Users/jeff/Desktop/test/names.txt");
        try{
        readLines(f);
        } catch  (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Q2)The part I am also having trouble with is the part where I need to create a loop to randomly assign values to each power of each instance of a class.
Here's what I've done so far

```
               {
               hero [] cards = new hero[cardNumber];
               for(int i=4;i<cardNumber;i++){ cards[i]=new hero();}
               Random rand = new Random();
               for(int i=0; i<cards.length; ++i)
               {
               cards[i].strength = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;
               cards[i].intellect = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;
               cards[i].flight = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;
               cards[i].tech = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;
               }
```

But when I print out the values all the instances have the same value for their powers.
Eg Card 12 Intelligence = 6
And Card 14 Intelligence = 6

Can anyone please help me with these issues, and any guidance will be highly appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is unanswerable without additional details. Please post your relevant code and data. See also the instructions on making minimal reproducible examples.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience